# Disable automatic serial port probing in Linux(Fedora)

Tags: linux, usb

I use a device that is connected to my Linux (Fedora21) PC via usb-com serial adapter. When device is connected and /dev/ttyACM0 is created in system
something sending a series of modem AT-command for it initialization.

Since my device is not modem, I would like to disable that behavior.

So the question is, how to disable such probing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The something that probes your port is most likely ModemManager, which is part of the NetworkManager suite.

If you have no (classic or wwan) modem installed in your system, the easiest thing to do is to remove ModemManager from your system. If you do have such a modem, then you can add a udev rule to signal to ModemManager that this device is not a modem and that it shouldn't even probe it:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1234", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5678", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
```

where `1234` is the vendor id of your device, and `5678` the product id (you can find these with `lsusb`)

Answer (score 0):

This is solution help me for ModemManager 1.10.0 with `--filter-policy=strict` (Ubuntu 18.04)
`ModemManager -V`

You can learn more: [Common udev tags](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/api/latest/ModemManager-Common-udev-tags.html)

Create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/49-stm32.rules` and add this:

```
# 0483:5740 - STM32 in USB Serial Mode (CN5)
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0483", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5740", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0483", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5740", ENV{ID_MM_TTY_BLACKLIST}="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0483", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5740", ENV{MTP_NO_PROBE}="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0483", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5740", ENV{ID_MM_PORT_IGNORE}="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0483", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5740", ENV{ID_MM_TTY_MANUAL_SCAN_ONLY}="1"
```

After save file and run:
`sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`

and (maybe it's not necessary):
`sudo systemctl restart ModemManager.service`

After reconnecting the USB device (physically pull  out and pull in it into the USB port) and enjoy.

P.S. This is a solution for the STM32 CDC Virtual Com port - if necessary, you can change the PID / VID and udev tags.